# Restrict file types in Strapi file upload

Tags: strapi

I'm using Strapi to create an API for a project and one content type has a media field called "image." For obvious reasons, I'd like to restrict the types of file uploads to just images.  It seems like it should be easy, but I don't see how to do that anywhere in the documentation.  Does anyone else have a solution?